# Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 2.12 — image of the unit Euclidean ball under affine mapping

Tags: convex-analysis, ellipsoids

In example 2.12 it is mentioned that the ellipsoid

$$\varepsilon = \{x \mid (x-x_c)^{T}P^{-1}(x-x_c)\leq 1\}$$

is the image of the unit euclidean ball $\{u \mid \|u\|_2\leq 1\}$ under the affine mapping $f(u) = P^{1/2} u + x_c$. What does this sentence mean?  Does it mean that if we apply the affine mapping on the condition (that determines unit euclidean ball) we will get $\varepsilon$? But if it is right then after the application of affine mapping I get

$$\left\{ u \mid \sqrt{(P^{1/2}u+x_c)^{T}(P^{1/2}u+x_c)}\leq 1 \right\}$$

which does not look to be equal to the equation written above for $\varepsilon$. However, if I apply the affine mapping on the defining condition for $\varepsilon$ then I do get the unit euclidean ball. So based on this I conclude that the affine mapping should be applied to the defining condition of the set which is the image.

On the other hand when I read the solution for problem 2.17 of same book I see that the functional mapping (not necessarily affine) is applied on the set whose image is needed. So I am confused about what convention to follow here. I will be very thankful if somebody explains me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ satisfies $\|u\|_2\leq 1$ then, as you can easily check, $x=f(u)=P^{1/2}u+x_c$ satisfies the condition mentioned in the definition of $\mathcal{E}$. That means that the image of the Euclidean ball under $f$ sits inside $\mathcal{E}$. It is not hard to find the inverse mapping.

I think the confusion arises because you went in the opposite direction with your substitutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But we know that the image of a set $C$ under mapping $f$ is defined as $$f(C)={f(x)|x\in C}$$. In this situation it becomes $$f({u|\|u\|_2}\leq1)={P^{1/2}u+x_c|\|u\|_2\leq 1}$$. I do not know how to show that $$\{P^{1/2}u+x_c|\|u\|_2\leq 1\}=\{x|(x-x_c)^TP^{-1}(x-x_c)\leq 1\}$$ I will be very thankful if you help in understanding this. Thanks in advance.